# setting environment variable on Mac

Tags: python, terminal

Setting the environment variable for a file that is located in a different folder.
I typed this in the terminal

the file is located in a folder named **pp** on the **desktop**

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/malbairmani/Desktop/pp"
```

Then I opened python in the terminal

```
Python3
```

then I tried to import my file (which is located in a different directory)
The file is named **five_a**

```
import five_a
```

I got this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'five_a'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`? The default login shell on macOS 10.15 is `zsh`, which means you should setting `PYTHONPATH` in `.zprofile` instead.

Comment: First check if your python path is actually set, with `import os` followed by `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` - you'll likely find this is not a Python problem but an environment problem.

Comment: can you walk me through the steps? @chepner

Comment: There are no steps. Just edit `.zprofile` instead of `.bash_profile`, creating the file if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, it worked